# TestPlan problem to activate trial period

Tags: azure-devops, trial, test-plan

I would like to use the **Azure DevOps Test Plan trial period** but, after I've activated it if i go in test plan page, i always see the message:

> *"You are currently logged in as a user with basic access level and you are seeing this page as you don't have any test plans and test suites created for the selected team."*

in the billing page i see:

> *"Basic + Test Plans - Trial expires in 30 days"*

so it seems to be active but not from **Test Plan Page**

someone has suggestions?

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 2):

Currently, when you enable the Test Plan, you need to manually switch your user's access level to Basic + Test Plan.

Go to **Organization Settings -> Users -> Choose the user that you want to change its access level -> More... -> Change access level -> Choose Basic + Test Plans**.

[image]

[image]